# Null Reference Exception in != Null while loop

Tags: c#

I'm getting a null reference exception that just doesn't make sense to me. It's being called on the last line of the while loop. File is basically a csv and always has 3 values separated by commas, each line needs to a a credit card object. It works if I do the split inside the loops with a different variable but I don't understand why.

```
using (StreamReader fileInput = File.OpenText("Assignment5.txt"))
{
    String[] line = fileInput.ReadLine().Split(',');

    while (line != null)     // read each line
    {
        cards.Add(new CreditCard(line[0], double.Parse(line[1]), double.Parse(line[2])));
        line = fileInput.ReadLine().Split(',');
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI https://filehelpers.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `fileInput.ReadLine()` returns **null** and you cant do the **split** there.

Try this approach adding some [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?.`)

```
using (StreamReader fileInput = File.OpenText("Assignment5.txt"))
    {
        //Add null operator here
        String[] line = fileInput.ReadLine()?.Split(',');
        while (line != null)//read each line
        {
            cards.Add(new CreditCard(line[0], double.Parse(line[1]), double.Parse(line[2])));
            //Add nulls operators here
            line = fileInput.ReadLine()?.Split(',');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah my thinking was too shallow was assuming it was saying line was null.

Comment: Yup it works, thanks for explaining and showing me something new.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `fileInput.ReadLine()` returns `null` and you can't call `Split()` it...

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code:

```
string[] line;

while ((line = fileInput.ReadLine().Split(',')) != null)     // read each line
    cards.Add(new CreditCard(line[0], double.Parse(line[1]), double.Parse(line[2])));
```

You can also use !string.IsNullOrWhitespace.
By the way, this code `line[0], double.Parse(line[1]), double.Parse(line[2])` is bugged.